# Configure gradle with annotationProcessor and log4j2 PluginProcessor

Tags: gradle, annotations

I was trying to build my project with gradle. I got this error:

```
"Detecting annotation processors on the compile classpath has been deprecated. Gradle 5.0 will ignore annotation processors on the compile classpath. The following annotation processors were detected on the compile classpath: 'org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.processor.PluginProcessor'.  Please add them to the annotation processor path instead. If you did not intend to use annotation processors, you can use the '-proc:none' compiler argument to ignore them."
```

I got that I have to use annotattionProcessor instead of compile. But how actually to do it.
Here is the part of my gradle file dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1'
}
```

I was trying to use it like this (implicit way), but it doesn't work

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1'
    annotationProcessor 'org.apache.logging.log4j.core:config.plugins.processor.PluginProcessor'
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 14):

The answer was pretty simple:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1'
    annotationProcessor 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1'
}
```

Comment: We had it working on Gradle 4.x without this! But looks like after Gradle 5, just having the log4j core jar in the classpath is not enough, you need the explicit `annotationProcessor` declaration for it to work.

Comment: Doesn't work.
With this config I get error "ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console..."